# Loading data in Hive table with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I'm looking to load data in Hive table by a .sql script but I get an issue like this :

```
hduser@master:~$ hive -f script.sql 

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/hduser/ecosystem/apache-hive-2.3.0-bin/lib/hive-common-2.3.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
OK
Time taken: 5.798 seconds
Loading data to table default.test
Failed with exception Unable to move source file:/home/hduser/Data.txt to destination hdfs://master:9000/user/hive/warehouse/test/Data.txt
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. Unable to move source file:/home/hduser/Data.txt to destination hdfs://master:9000/user/hive/warehouse/test/Data.txt
```

My script looks like :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (
id int, mdp string, id_employe int, category int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/hduser/Data.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE Test ;
```

Permissions in `/home/hduser` are :

```
hduser@master:~$ ls -l
total 5364168
-rwx-wx-wx 1 hduser hduser 5492885458 août  24 11:38 Data.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hduser hduser        684 août  24 12:14 derby.log
drwxrwxr-x 3 hduser hduser       4096 juil. 26 11:46 ecosystem
drwxrwxr-x 5 hduser hduser       4096 août  24 12:14 metastore_db
-rwx-wx-wx 1 hduser hduser        233 août  24 12:10 script.sql
```

Data looks like :

```
1, jhkjhkjh, 18, 11
2, poilll, 87, 13
3, aoudliaoiud, 98, 76
...
```

In `http://172.30.10.182:50070/explorer.html#/` I have :

```
drwx-wx-wx  hduser  supergroup  0 B Aug 24 11:40    0   0 B tmp
then
drwx-wx-wx  hduser  supergroup  0 B Aug 24 11:40    0   0 B hive
then 
drwx-wx-wx  hduser  supergroup  0 B Aug 24 12:14    0   0 B hduser
then 
drwx-wx-wx  hduser  hduser  0 B Aug 24 12:12    0   0 B warehouse
then 
drwx-wx-wx  hduser  hduser  0 B Aug 24 12:12    0   0 B test
```

Do you have any idea why I can fill my test table with data from Data.txt ?

Answer (score 1):

The directory that you are tying to write the file to is

```
/user/hive/warehouse/test/
```

The rights that you check via the explorer are for

```
/tmp/hive/warehouse/test/
```

So here is a clear mismatch.

Comment: Where I have to specify that the well directory is `/tmp/...` ? in my .xml files ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have permission issue in haddop. provide permission using below one command and also verify that data.txt file is not corrupt

hadoop fs -chmod g+w /user/hive/warehouse/test/

Comment: I tried both things but none works. I can't access to `master:19888` too

Comment: it's related to permission. you have to root permission to above command then you can do.

Comment: sudo with your command ? But `sudo hadoop ...` say : hadoop command not found